# IE9 tabbable div inside form not submit?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, accessibility

When creating a tabbable div inside a form, most browsers don't submit the form when the div is focused and enter is pressed.

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/SBfKs/3/

IE9 does though for some reason. Does anyone know how to override this in IE9 to make it consistent across browsers?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting, I didn't know IE would submit the form in this case.

You could trap keypresses (IE submits on `keydown`) and cancel the default behavior if on a `<div>`. If `<div>` is the only element you're going to add the ability to focus on, this should fix the issue (jQuery solution):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $form = $('#foo');
    $form.on('keydown', 'div', function(e) {
        code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (code === 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/SBfKs/9/)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the sort of override I was looking for!